# How to kill a process created by subprocess by another function?

Tags: python, subprocess, terminate

I'm wondering why I can't terminate a batch file raised from one function by using another function.

What I'm trying to do is to manage the batch file on my dedicated computer by [Telebot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

My `test.bat` file:

```bat
title test.bat
timeout /t 999
```

I've written a separated module  with functions to start and kill this batch file:

```python
from os import path, kill
import subprocess
import signal


TEST_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\TEST\\'
un_proc = None 


class sidim(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def launch_test(self):
        test_proc = subprocess.Popen([path.join(TEST_PATH,
                                                'TEST.bat')],                                                                              
                          creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
        self.test_pid = test_proc.pid

    def kill_test(self):
        kill(self.test_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

And when I'm starting the batch file using the `/start_test` command it works fine and the batch file is launching properly:

```python
import telebot 
import sidimanager

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
sidim = sidimanager.sidim()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start_test'])
def handle_start_test(message):
    sidim.launch_test()
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Test .bat file has been successfuly launched.')
```

But when I'm trying to terminate this batch with the `/kill_test` command the batch file ignores that and continues to work:

```python
@bot.message_handler(commands='kill_test')
def handle_kill_test(message):
    sidim.kill_test()
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Test .bat file has been successfuly killed.')
```

How can I kill it?

Comment: Can you show the batch-file as well ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, sure, but it just a placeholder .bat in order to reuse it several times:     `title test.bat
timeout /t 999`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your batch file. We need enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @double-beep, done, but I don't think that the content of batch file is the real issue.

Comment: Me too, but we couldn't think so if you didn't post it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am calling the batch through a new `cmd.exe` process. In some cases, it feels that the commands in the batch are running in the 'background':

```
import subprocess

test_proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd',  '/c',  'C:/temp/myBatch.bat'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
test_pid = test_proc.pid
```

Now you are having the batch running isolated in a new CMD process, that can be easily killed using `taskkill /F /PID 1234` via Popen.

**Note**: You might need to provide full paths to `cmd.exe, taskkill.exe and your batch`, depending on how your 'main script' is started.

Comment: Sorry, for being vague: [Popen.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill)

Comment: Thankyou, I've tried  this `def kill_test(self):
            command = ['TASKKILL', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(self.pid)]
            subprocess.Popen(command)` and batch is finally dead.